# Looking for a possible counterexample

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Continuing from the problem of this link:

[Domain of Linear operator forming a Hilbert Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209913/domain-of-linear-operator-forming-a-hilbert-space/2210392?noredirect=1#comment4548301_2210392)

If I try to work backwards, and pose the question that:

> Give an example of $(H, <\cdot,\cdot>_{H}, ||\cdot||_{H})$ a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space and $A : D(A) (\subseteq H) \to H$ be a diagonal linear operator with $\sigma_{P}(A) \subseteq (0,\infty)$ such that triple $(D(A), <A(\cdot),A(\cdot))>, ||A(\cdot)||_{H})$ is NOT a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert Space

Then what do I need?? Please let me know if I am wrong.

i) I need $D(A)$ to contain a Cauchy Sequence of real-valued functions which converge to some complex limit.

ii) This $D(A)$ has to be eligible to be a domain of a diagonal linear operator $A$

and

iii) A has to have all positive eigen values in its point-spectrum.

Isn't it??

Comment: Because the spectrum is closed and contained in $(0,\infty)$, then your operator is semibounded. Then your previous problem applies.

Answer (score 1):

You can either say you want a Cauchy sequence in $D(A)$ wrt the norm $x\mapsto \|Ax\|$ that does not converge or you can say you want a Cauchy sequence in $\mathrm{im}(A)$ that does not converge to a point in$\mathrm{im}(A)$.

It is not necessary to consider unbounded operators, for example look at the operator:
$$A:\ell^2(\Bbb N)\to\ell^2(\Bbb N),\ \sum_n^\infty x_ne_n\mapsto \sum_n^\infty 4^{-n}x_n e_n$$
Now the finitely supported sequences lie in the image of $A$, but the element $\sum_n^\infty 2^{-n}e_n=\lim_N \sum_n^N 2^{-n}e_n$ does not lie in the image, since its preimage would necessarily be $\sum_n^\infty 2^n e_n$, which does not live in $\ell^2$.

Comment: Thanks!! So, finally we can say that the intuition was correct and the inf$\sigma_{P}(A) > 0$ is really strong condition and without that there exist examples such that $(D(A), <A(\cdot),A(\cdot))>, ||A(\cdot)||_{H})$ is NOT a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert Space.

Comment: Oh, excuse me, I somehow forgot $0\notin\sigma(A)$. This example is wrong in this case. Indeed for bounded $A$ with $0\notin\sigma(A)$ and global domain $\mathrm{im}(A)$ is a Hilbert space.

Comment: If $0\notin\sigma(A)$ then $A$ must be invertible and $\mathrm{im}(A)=H$ and this is a Hilbert space.

Comment: I am following these two threads with curiosity. And I think the question posed here is wrong to the best of my knowledge. There is probably no such counterexample!

Comment: @user92360  Although, I must admit I am optimistic about the existence of such an example for unbounded  linear operator!!

Comment: @user86511 The condition $0\notin\sigma(A)$ means $A:D(A)\to H$ is invertible, ie $1$-to-$1$ and $D(A)$ with norm $\|A\cdot\|$ becomes the same as $H$.

Answer (score 1):

To get some things straight: This has nothing to do with complex numbers.
$\inf \sigma_P(A)>0$ is much stronger than $\sigma_P(A) \subset (0,\infty)$. You need unbounded operators (otherwise their domain is closed, hence Hilbert).

Try $A:\ell^2\to\ell^2$, $(Ax)_k = 2^kx_k$.

Comment: @ Dirk, are you asking to try with this operator $A:l^{2}(\mathbb N) \to l^{2}(\mathbb N)$, defined by $\sum_n^\infty x_ne_n\mapsto \sum_n^\infty 2^{n}x_n e_n$ ?? which is unbounded for sure. And, it maps any Cauchy Sequence to NOT-Cauchy sequence (being divergent!!!). Isn't it ??

Comment: This specific operator does make the space $(D(A),\langle A\cdot,A\cdot\rangle)$ into a Hilbert space. Indeed of $0\notin\sigma(A)$ you should always have that $(D(A),\langle A\cdot,A\cdot\rangle)$ is a Hilbert space.

Comment: As far as I see, you do not need the operator to be bounded. Try to find out what $D(A)$ is.